# Wikipedia image API search - get only images with Creative Commons license

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikimedia-commons

We search Wikipedia images by API call:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=%22Einstein%22&srnamespace=6
```

(in this example by search query "Einstein")

Thanks to [Retrieving image license and author information in wiki commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453654/retrieving-image-license-and-author-information-in-wiki-commons) we know already how to retrieve the image license which could be:

- CC-BY
- CC-BY-SA
- CC-0
- PD
- GNU

Is it possible to filter images with Creative Commons licenses (CC-0, CC-BY and CC-BY-SA) already in the search? We want to avoid to remove PD- and GNU-images from the results.

Comment: Any update on this question? I'm also interested to find CC licensed images from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. I don't see any mention of anything like this in [the documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Imageinfo)